# how to fix connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? error when running bitbucket pipelines

Tags: python, django, postgresql, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to run tests using bitbucket pipelines but unfortunately, I can not connect with postgresql.

So I have tried adding `rm -rf /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432/` to my bitbucket-pipeline.yml but nothing has changed when running my test

This is the error that I get

```sh
+ python manage.py test
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:265: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.
  RuntimeWarning
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=accounts,rest_v1, property --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 174, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: python:3.6.2
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - python manage.py test

  branches:
    develop:
    - step:
        caches:
        - node
        script:
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python manage.py test
```

setting.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    }
}
```

I expect bitbucket pipelines to run the test without issues especially DB connection issues

Comment: you need to restart/start your postgreSQL server, your server isn't accepting connection

Comment: which server... local postgreSQL server? if so my local postgreSQL server is running seamlessly

Comment: have you created database with 'db_name'?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `services` key and do something similar to what they have in the `definition` of the service as well.

```
pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
            image: node
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm test
            services:
              - postgres

definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: pipelines
        POSTGRES_USER: test_user
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_user_password
```

Source:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-use-Postgres-in-Bitbucket-Pipelines/qaq-p/461910

Comment: is there a different or another error ? it works for others, it must be something in your configuration. good luck